# useEffect and ESlint exhaustive-deps rule

Tags: reactjs, eslint, eslint-plugin-react-hooks

I'm currently stuck on how to build my logic without having any warning about **`exhaustive-deps`** in my `useEffect`.

My goal is to track navigation (enter page date, leave page date and location) on location change.

I am using `useLocation()` of `react-router-dom` and `useLastLocation()` of `react-router-last-location`.

```
const location = useLocation()
const lastLocation = useLastLocation()

const [date, setDate] = React.useState(new Date())

React.useEffect(() => {
  const end = new Date()
  API.sendData({ start: date, end, location: lastLocation })
  setDate(end)
}, [location, lastLocation])
```

**This is working fine** but my `useEffect` dependencies array should contains `date` to not have `exhaustive-deps` warning, but adding it, will make infinite loops.

What is the correct way to do it ?

Comment: I would probably have a look at `history.listen()` and register a function that logs the pages and the time when the function is called to get the data that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The useState dispatch also allows you to provide a function that accepts the current value as an argument rather than simply a value. That way you could avoid the `date` as a dependency.

```js
const location = useLocation()
const lastLocation = useLastLocation()

const [date, setDate] = React.useState(new Date())

React.useEffect(() => {
  setDate((currentDate) => {
    const end = new Date();
    API.sendData({ start: currentDate, end, location: lastLocation });
    return end;
  });
}, [location, lastLocation]);
```